# What is the unit for raw data in Kinect V2?

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

I am trying to figure out what is the raw data in Kinect V2? ... I know we can convert these raw data to meters and to gray color to represent the depth .... but what is the unit of these raw data ? 
and why all the images that captured by Kinect are mirrored?

Answer (score 0):

The raw values stored in the depth image are in millimeters. You can get the X and Y values using the pixel position along with the depth camera intrinsic parameters. If you want I could share a Matlab code that converts the depth image into X,Y,Z values.

Yes, the images are mirrored in Windows-SDK and in the "[libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2)" which is a open source version of SDK. I couldn't get a solid answer why it is so, but you could look at the discussion available in the [link](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/172).

Answer (score 0):

There are different kinds of frame which can be captured through Kinect V2. Every raw data captured has a different unit. Like, for depth frame it is millimeters, for color it is RGB (0-255, 0-255, 0-255), for bodyFrames it is 0 or 1 ( having same resolution as depth frame, but can identify up-to a maximum number of human bodies at a time ) and etc.
Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect